# Equation counter automatically resets after using \tag

Tags: memoir, counters

I am currently writing my master thesis, and I have just noticed that I have a problem, that I don't know how to solve. My thesis is divided into several chapters. In the first chapter I have an equation, which I want to state again in the second chapter, with the same equation number. To do this I use \tag, by writing `\tag{\ref{eq:1}}`. The problem is that after doing this, the equation counter resets. So now I have two different equations labeled (2.1).

I have been trying to cook up a minimal working example, but I can't really spot the error. So I have made an example to show what I am doing, but when I compile it, it looks as it should.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
First equation
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
abc
\end{equation}

\chapter{Second}
Second equation
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:2}
xyz
\end{equation}
\eqref{eq:2}

Lets recap \eqref{eq:1}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:3}
abc \tag{\ref{eq:1}}
\end{equation}
Ref: \eqref{eq:3}

And another equation
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:4}
ijk
\end{equation}
Ref: \eqref{eq:4}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is - or even more importantly, how I solve it?

Comment: I have found a solution myself. The solution was to add the line `\refstepcounter{equation}%` between the tagged equation, and the equation with the wrong label. However, I think that this might only work, since the label it should have is (2.2), instead of (2.1) as it has been reset to.

If anyone comes up with a better solution, please post it here! Someone (e.g. me) might learn something.

By the way, I don't have enough reputation to post an answer to my own question yet.

Comment: Your MWE do not produce the problem you mention when I compile it.

Comment: I know. I don't know what causes the error in my large document. I tried coming up with a MWE, but as you see it didn't go too well, although it shows what I'm trying to do.

Comment: With a MWE that doesn't actually show the issue, we are unlikely to solve this.